# Stiff Equations - What to plot as a qualitative or quantitative measure of stiffness

Tags: finite-difference, stiffness

On a recommendation from [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), I am posting this on Computational Science.SE:

I am trying to quantify stiffness of an ODE by relating it to the fine-ness with which NDSolve  treats it's time step.

### BACKGROUND

**For the uninitiated:**

Essentially, when an ordinary differential equation is stiff and we attempt to solve it with NDSolve in *Mathematica*, it would employ a stiff solver to detect and reconcile stiffness.

I use the [stiff equation shown on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation) to demonstrate this. This equation is solved using BDF (backward difference formulation/formula) which is a recognized method to solve stiff equations.

**Equation and solution using NDSolve with BDF**

```
tMax=100;
rSol=
r/.NDSolve[
r'[t]==-15 r[t]&&r[0]==1,r,
{t,0,tMax},Method->{"BDF","MaxDifferenceOrder"->5}][[1]]
```

**Plots of solution r vs t**

```
{Plot[
rSol[t],
{t,0,100},
PlotRange->{{0,tMax},Automatic}
],
LogPlot[
rSol[t],
{t,0,100},
PlotRange->{{0,tMax},Automatic}
]}
```

**Fig 1**

[image]

**Fig 2**

[image]

Fig 1 shows that up to t=29.9 or so, there is considerable stiffness (unstable oscillations) that is reconciled by ensuring that the time step is sufficiently small.

### **THE REAL QUESTION:**

What would be a good plot to quantify this stiffness and internal reconciliation/changing of time step? How can I best quantify stiffness graphically in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! Please include the ODE (and its initial conditions) using LaTeX syntax so that non-Mathematica users can better understand your example.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/06/09/ordinary-differential-equations-stiffness/?s_tid=Blog_Cleve_Category

Comment: Someone (Gustaf Soderlind) has finally proposed a quantitative measure of stiffness that experts are beginning to agree on.  See [this paper](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~ljay/publications.dir/Stiffnessdefinitionold.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Stiffness has no precise quantitative definition. (See my answer [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/892/276).)

Common numerical proxies would be things like:

- stiffness ratio: find the (unsigned) ratio of largest magnitude eigenvalue to smallest magnitude eigenvalue of the Jacobian matrix of your right-hand side; estimates are probably fine
- ratio of time step taken to maximum stable time step: a ratio closer to 1 indicates a stability-limited time step, so your problem is probably stiff; a ratio closer to 0 indicates an accuracy-limited time step, and probably a non-stiff problem

There may be other metrics out there; these are the first two that come to mind.

Comment: Yes, I am currently trying to plot item 2 of your description. Will put that down here as an answer soon.